# Socket programming in Python error: "group argument must be None for now" and "SocketErr Errno. 111"

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to implement socket programming using Python.

**server.py**

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
try:
    from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn, ForkingMixIn
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
except ImportError:
    from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn, ForkingMixIn
    from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler



#from SocketServer import ThreadingMIxIn
class ClientThread(Thread):

    def _init_(self,ip,port):
        Thread._init_(self)
        self.ip=ip
        self.port= port
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + + ":" + str(port))

    def run(self):
        while True :
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            print ("Server received data:", data)
            MESSAGE = raw_input("Multithreaded Python Server : Enter response from sever Enter exit:")

            if MESSAGE == 'exit' :
        #break
                conn.send(MESSAGE) 


TCP_IP ='0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 2024
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

tcpServer = socket.socket()
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
threads=[]


while True:
    tcpServer.listen(4)
    print ("Multithreaded python server: Waiting for connections from tcp clients...")
    (conn ,(ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept()
    newthread=ClientThread(ip,port)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)


for t in threads:
    t.join() #end
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

host=socket.gethostname()
port=2024
BUFFER_SIZE= 2000
MESSAGE = raw_input("tcpClientB: Enter message / Enter exit:")

tcpClientB =socket.socket()
tcpClientB.connect((host, port))

while MESSAGE !='exit':
    tcpClientB.send(MESSAGE)
    data=tcpClientB.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print ("Client received data",data)
    MESSAGE=raw_input("tcpClientB: Enter message to continue/ Enter exit:")

tcpClientB.close()
```

When I am trying to run this, first `server.py` and then `client.py`, I get this error for `server.py`

```
Multithreaded python server: Waiting for connections from tcp clients...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mserver.py", line 47, in <module>
    newthread=ClientThread(ip,port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 670, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

and the following error from `client.py`:

```
python client2.py 
tcpClientB: Enter message / Enter exit:exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mclient2.py", line 10, in <module>
    tcpClientB.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. And when I am entering `exit` in client after running it gives me `SocketErr Errno. 111`.

Comment: `_init_` -> `__init__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errno 111 means 'connection refused'. The server refuses the connection because it crashes due to error in the Thread constructor call. The constructor in python is `__init__` (double double underscore).

Your program just defines a method *init* instead of constructor and the first argument of Thread constructor is a group.

Change your server to

```
def __init__(self,ip,port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
```